# reduce compression artifacts (using madVR as filter for ffmpeg?)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

madVR has a filter called 'reduce compression artifacts' which produces a very good quality output image on 'live playback'. I would like to permanently apply this filter to a video. Is it possible to use madVR as a filter for ffmpeg to generate a permanent output file? Thanks! [madVR filter settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v95yV.png)

Comment: No, unless madVR can output a file or pipe that ffmpeg can use as an input. But if you show a before and after example perhaps existing ffmpeg filters can do something.

Comment: It basically smooths out the picture, everything gets a bit of an artificial look but the compression artifacts are mostly gone.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the many postprocessing filters:

- [spp](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#spp) - Simple Postprocessing
- [uspp](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#uspp) - Ultra Simple or Slow Postprocessing
- [fspp](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fspp) - Fast Simple Postprocessing
- [pp7](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pp7) - Postprocessing 7
- [pp](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pp) - libpostproc wrapper

---

[image: Before]
<sub>Original</sub>

[image: After]
<sub>Postprocessed</sub>

---

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "spp=5:10:0:1" -c:a copy output
```

See more examples at [FFmpeg Wiki: Postprocessing](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Postprocessing).